# VSCode producing wrong ESLint Prettier error

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

After saving my .tsx file in VSCode, Eslint/Prettier changes the order of the Tailwind classes. However, when I run Eslint in my terminal, it shows this reordering as an error.

VSCode correct:

```
className='grid [grid-column:1_/_span_2] [grid-row:1_/_span_2] [grid-template-columns:subgrid] [grid-template-rows:subgrid]'>
```

Terminal correct:

```
className='grid [grid-template-columns:subgrid] [grid-template-rows:subgrid] [grid-column:1_/_span_2] [grid-row:1_/_span_2]'>
```

Error message:

```
Replace `template-columns:subgrid]·[grid-template-rows:subgrid]·[grid-column:1_/_span_2]·[grid-row:1_/_span_2` with `column:1_/_span_2]·[grid-row:1_/_span_2]·[grid-template-columns:subgrid]·[grid-template-rows:subgrid`eslintprettier/prettier
```

How can I make sure VSCode and Terminal both agree on the same ESLint/Prettier configuration?

Here's my configuration:

- Yarn Workspace:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "server",
    "shared",
    "web"
  ]
```

- VSCode settings:

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.addMissingImports": true,
    "source.fixAll": true,
   },
   "eslint.workingDirectories": [
     "./web",
     ".",
   ]
}
```